# Intelhaxm has made iMac unable to start up

Tags: macos, graphics, startup, haxm

After installing opencore on my 27inch 2009 Imac I was able to successfully install OS Monterey onto the mac via a usb bootloader. All good. Now I had been attempting to use android studio but could not emulate any virtual devices on the software for some reason. Wouldn’t even appear on the software. And so I saw online that installing intelhaxm solved the issue for some. After installing, the intelhaxm installer prompted me that I needed to restart the computer for it to take effect. Now after restarting my mac, the startup loading bar freezes half way and does not continue. I am stuck.

After accessing terminal through recovery mode, I attempt to find and uninstall haxm but the terminal simply tells me that nothing with that name exists. I really would like to get this working again, does anyone have a solution?